# Is it rude to say "stolen from here"?

Tags: discussion, attribution, plagiarism

When I'm answering a question (not a duplicate one), I often **copy-paste** some contents from another answer and **also provide the link** to that answer. I think adding the link itself contradicts stealing, therefore, saying "stolen from this link" would add an obvious humorous flavour to my post.

But since some people complained about this wording, considering [attribution requirements](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/). Is it considered **rude or abusive** to the author (or anyone else) if I say: *stolen from this link* ?

Comment: The quotation and citation of a source material are perfectly fine.  It's a practice that is recognized by nearly everyone.  Anyone that has a problem with a citing external source obviously does not know the various writing rules, that exists for a reason. If you cite something properly, then it's not plagiarism, and thus it cannot be stolen from the author you are citing.

Comment: @Ramhound this is exactly my point. Such an obvious paradox can only be an obvious joke, which apparently few people get!

Comment: Seems like a sort of pointless joke, that has very little humor involved honestly, I would remove such a statement as noise.

Comment: `I often copy-paste some contents from another answer` why not flag as dup?

Comment: @AlexL because it is not a duplicate. but a new problem built around another problem (or other several problems)

Comment: Why is this question down-voted? Is there any way to improve it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'd just say "copied from here" instead; that's the 'professional' way of saying it. Your version might work as a joke, or if you're on especially friendly terms with the original author, but it's likely to be interpreted in the wrong way. It's not rude/abusive, it's just out of place (most of the times).